# AWS CLI Rename API Gateway model

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

I'm trying to do something I expected to be really simple.

I'd like to simply rename a model created on my API Gateway through the AWS CLI scripting tool (using powershell).

I have had a look at lots of documentation, including [this aws document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/update-model.html), with which I can do pretty much anything on the model, except rename it.

I expected it to be something like:

```
aws apigateway update-model --rest-api-id RESTID --model-name 'ModelName' --
patch-operations op=replace,path=/name,value='NewModelName' --region 
AWSREGION
```

Which is almost identical to how to update a model description:

```
aws apigateway update-model --rest-api-id RESTID --model-name 'MDescription' 
--patch-operations op=replace,path=/description,value='NewDescription' 
--region ap-southeast-2
```

Is there a particular reason why we cannot rename these models, or have I just missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Gateway does not support renaming a model.

The model name is used as the unique identifier for the model and can be referenced from many different resources/methods within the API.  This makes implementing a rename operation very difficult as an arbitrary number of references would also need to be updated at the same time.

Comment: And this is even though the model has an ID attached to it? Something like `"contentType": "application/json", "id": "0jho11", "name": "ModelName"`?

Comment: Yes, the model does have an id attached to it and it should have been possible to implement references by id without using the name.  Unfortunately, this was not how it was done.  All of the references to the model are done by name.